# Is it safe to delete the default Document content type that is created by default with a document library in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type

I have a document library in a SharePoint Site where I have created my own custom content type that inherits from Document called "My Special Document". (It has a few optional columns associated with it).

Is it ok if I delete the default "Document" content type and leave "My Special Document" as the only content type in this library?

Will this cause random issues in the future as new features roll out with Teams, OneDrive and SharePoint Online? (from what I can tell it should be fine, but want to double check).

Appreciate if I anyone with Microsoft contacts could further validate this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t have a document based on the default document content type, you can delete it in this library, leaving only your custom content type.

Otherwise,it cannot be deleted.

And there will be no other impact.